# How to make different dataframes using split

Tags: r

I know the split command is the easiest way to turn a df into a list of df objects, but how can they be assigned to different (seperated) dataframes?

```
df.List <- split(df, df$column)
```

Comment: I don't really understand your question. What is the different between a list of data.frames and different data.frames? And why you want to avoid using a list?

Comment: Rubberduck myself! In my case, the split argument contains a long string. So calling each "subset" is hard. Renaming the subset is a better solution.

nam <- c("Q1","Q2","Q3","Q4","Q5","Q6")
for (i in 1:length(nam)) {
 assign(nam[i], df.List[[i]])
}

Comment: Do you want to post it as an answer to help people with the same question in the future?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Look at the function `list2env`. Try:

```
list2env(split(df, df$column), envir = .GlobalEnv)
```

Comment: That would a very simple and easy solution!
As mentioned, my variable contains strings, so with **list2env** they become my column names. Thanks!

Comment: @Oblmns, sorry. I don't quite understand your comment. Perhaps if you post some sample data and an example of the output you would be looking for, I can update my answer to be more meaningful.

Comment: a <- c("some long text with another word", "more words in a long sentence", "this word contains multiple letters")
b <- c(1,2,3)
x <-data.frame(a,b)
After split(x, x$a) and using list2env $a will be my df names. right?

Comment: @Oblmns, yes, but since there are spaces in them, you'll need to access them using backticks, for example `\`more words in a long sentence\``

Answer (score 1):

Hereby my solution (example with the iris dataset)

two way:

```
list_df <- split(iris, iris$Species) #split the dataset into a list of datasets based on the value of iris$Species
list2env(list_DF, envir= .GlobalEnv) #split the list into separate datasets
```

one way:

```
list2env(split(iris, iris$Species), envir = .GlobalEnv)
```

Or you can assign custom names for the new datasets with a `for` loop:

```
iris_split <- split(iris, iris$Species)
new_names <- c("one", "two", "three")
for (i in 1:length(iris_split)) {
  assign(new_names[i], iris_split[[i]])
```