# Create data tables for export based on values in a column

Tags: r, for-loop, data.table

Using [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19882085/subset-dataframe-using-a-loop) as a starting point, if my data appears like this:

```
index   state  date              Amount
2       FL     2010-06-08         0
21      FL     2010-10-08        10
6       FL     2010-08-16        30
5       GA     2010-11-25        20
9       GA     2010-01-01         0
8       CA     2011-03-06        10
12      CA     2012-03-12        10
11      CA     2012-06-21        10
15      NY     2010-01-01        30
13      NY     2010-04-06        20
```

How do I use the loop example from that question's highest voted answer to create data tables for export that are named based on the state value?  My goal is to export each state-specific data table to csv for separate analyses.  These are large datasets so prefer using data.table package.

Below is the loop from the question linked above using the `iris` dataset.

```
iris_split <- split(iris, iris$Species)
new_names <- c("one", "two", "three")
for (i in 1:length(iris_split)) {
  assign(new_names[i], iris_split[[i]])
}
```

Comment: You can use the same code.  just change the `assign` part to write.csv i.e. `write.csv(iris_split[[i]], paste0(new_names[i], ".csv"), quote = FALSE, row.names = FALSE)`

Comment: sorry, but in the example `new_names` is hard-coded rather than automatically pulling from the state value so this is not the full solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We could either `split` as in the solution posted in the link and then loop over the names of the list (`split` creates a named `list`), and do either `write.csv` or `fwrite` (from `data.table` as it would be fast for larger datasets)

```
library(data.table)
my_list <- split(df1, df1$state)
for(nm in names(my_list)) 
   {
     fwrite(my_list[[nm]], paste0(nm, ".csv"))
   }
```

---

Or another option would be a standard `data.table` group by approach.   Here, we grouped by 'state' (after converting the `data.frame` to `data.table` - `setDT`), then `fwrite` the subset of data.table (`.SD` - doesn't include the group column, and write to a file created with grouping column values (`.BY`).  For large datasets, removing a column can save some space as it is the same value that got repeated.  Instead, we can identify with the file name

```
setDT(df1)[, fwrite(.SD, file.path(getwd(), paste0(.BY, ".csv"))), by = state]
```

Answer (score 3):

Using `fwrite` from data.table

```
library(data.table)
my_list <- split(df, df$state)
lapply(seq_along(my_list), function(i){
   fwrite(my_list[[i]], paste0(names(my_list)[i], ".csv"))
})
```

Comment: Perhaps `seq_len(length(my_list))` -> `seq_along(my_list)`?

Comment: Yes, that`s much better @r2evans